# Aligning container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a span which has to aligned bottom and left-most to the content of it's container. Span text-node and container text-node font-size may differ.

Whatever it's span should always align to its container text-node bottom and to left-most. I tried using float left to the `span` node. It aligns to the left most but not to it's bottom. Removing `float` to the span, Aligns bottom but not left most. Sorry if I have not explained you better.

Refer the image attached for more clarification[image]

Also here is the code which I tried:

```css
.flexCtn{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background:#fff;
}
.w100{
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:right
}
span{
  font-size:14px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexCtn">
    <div class="w100">
      <span>check</span>
      the alignment
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S I don't want any modification to the DOM. I have specific reason for this DOM structure which is going ti be vague if i'm going to explain you guys. Also don't want absolute position to be applied for the `span`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `flexbox` container - so why not make `w100` also a `flexbox` and align *vertically* using `align-items: center` - see demo below:

```css
.flexCtn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background: #fff;
}
.w100 {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
span {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexCtn">
  <div class="w100">
    <span>check</span>
    the alignment
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Future users, and yourself, always benefit of knowing which answer best solved each question, and since this answer appeared to solve your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flex property

https://plnkr.co/edit/flxsEcpSBe8sr2w3wPFc?p=preview

```
      div{
          font-size:14px;
          display:flex;
          align-items:flex-end;
          flex:1;
         }
```

Comment: I have mentioned absolute should not be used in my post script

Comment: sorry i didnt noticed that..but i changed span to div :).  You already got working solution.. just tried it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexCtn{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background:#fff;
}
.w100{
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:right
}
span{
  font-size:14px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  padding : 16px 0 0 0; /* specify top position */
}
```

```html
<div class="flexCtn">
    <div class="w100">
      <span>check</span>
      the alignment
    </div>
</div>
```